# DataGrid DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource Binding not working

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to bind my `DataGridComboBoxColumn` on a `ObservableCollection<string> Values`. For this I wrote this `.xaml` code:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding FilterMng.FilterCollection}" CanUserAddRows="False" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Wert" Width="*" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding SelectedValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Values}"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Values}"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

`FilterMng.cs` is the manager class of `Filter.cs`. It contains a `ObservableCollection<Filter> FilterCollection{get;set;}` and some methods like `public void CreateFilter(){}`. But this methods works. When I execute the method `CreateFilter();` the `DataGrid` shows one more entry.

My `Filter.cs` code:

```
public class Filter : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Properties

    ObservableCollection<string> Values { get; set; }

    private string _selectedProperty;
    public string SelectedProperty
    {
        get { return this._selectedProperty; }
        set { this._selectedProperty = value; this.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedProperty"); }
    }

    private string _selectedValue;
    public string SelectedValue
    {
        get { return this._selectedValue; }
        set { this._selectedValue = value; this.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedValue"); }
    }

    #endregion Properties

    #region c'tor

    public Filter()
    {
        if (this.Values == null)
            this.Values = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        Values.Add("Entry1");
    }

    #endregion c'tor

    #region OnPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion OnPropertyChanged
}
```

I can bind on all propertys except `Values`.

Now I used Snoop to check if there any `ItemsSource` errors. THere exists an error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Values' property not found on 'object' ''Filter' (HashCode=31703865)'. BindingExpression:Path=Values; DataItem='Filter' (HashCode=31703865); target element is 'TextBlockComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')
```

Got anyone of you an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ObservableCollection<string> Values { get; set; }
```

In this setter property, you are not notifying which property is changed

Try something like this

```
private ObservableCollection<string> values;
public ObservableCollection<string> Values { get { return values; } set {values = value; this.OnPropertyChanged("Values ");} }
```

I am sure that is the problem with your code